# Почему при проверке на простоту перебирают значения только до квадратного корня?

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Часто задачи на определение простоты числа решают по такому алгоритму - перебирают все числа начиная с 2 и пытаются разделить проверяемое число на каждое, пока не встретится нулевой остаток. Если встретился- значит число не простое.

Но перебор ведут до квадратного корня из проверяемого числа. И я никак не пойму, почему это так? Почему делитель не может встретиться среди чисел больше квадратного корня от проверяемого?

Comment: Потому что корень из числа является как бы __максимальным__ возможным делитем числа, отличным от него самого. Возьмите лист бумаги и попробуйте найти простые делители для нескольких чисел - например для 9 и для 30 ;)

Comment: @MaxU Ну я вобщем-то верю, что это так, я просто не понимаю ПОЧЕМУ это так :)

Comment: @MaxU кстати говоря, 30 не подходит сюда. Оно не простое и делится и на 10 и на 15, а 10 и 15 > корня из 30.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров, _перебирают все числа начиная с 2_ - вы же сами это написали, вот и получены пары (2, 15), (3, 10).

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров, прстые делители числа 30: 2, 3, 5. А 5 < sqrt(30) ;)

Comment: @MaxU "является как бы максимальным возможным делитем числа, отличным от него самого". Просто вы имели в виду *простым* делителем. Поэтому я немного не въехал.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров, да я имел в виду максимальным возможным __простым__  делителем - не точно выразился

Comment: прчитайте любую книгу по теории числам - там это все выводится

Comment: с непростым делителем та же история =)
если найден делитель ,меньший корня из делимого, значит, будет получен результат деления (частное),  который больше корня. А это частное по определению само является делителем и проверять его нет смысла.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если число не простое, то оно имеет как минимум два множителя, которые должны быть меньше(либо равны) корня из исходного числа, иначе бы их произведение было бы больше оного, поэтому нет смысла перебирать стоящие далее числа.

Comment: Небольшая поправка - по крайней мере одно из них меньше или равно корню. Например для 10 множителями являются 5 и 2. 5 больше корня из 10, но его парный множитель 2 - меньше. Соответственно, если мы перебрали все числа до корня и не нашли делителя, то дальше перебирать бесполезно, т.к. всё равно не получится правильной пары делителей.

Comment: @Xander Если еще точнее- ровно одно меньше, а второе больше квадратного корня.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, ещё есть вариант, когда оба равны корню.

Comment: @Xander, ну да, забыл про крайний вариант :)

Comment: @Xander, можно подробнее про `5 больше корня из 10`? PS а то я начинаю переставать верить в красоту математики: `5^2 < sqrt(10) ^ 2` или `25 < 10`;-)

Comment: @MaxU Корень из 10 это число больше 3 и меньше 4. И поэтому корень из 10 в любом случае меньше чем 5. Так что с красотой математики все нормально.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, спасибо, я в курсе - это был легкий сарказм ) Просто не понял фразы: `"5 больше корня из 10"` и особенно `"ровно одно меньше, а второе больше квадратного корня"` (с) Юрий Козлов

Comment: @pepsicoca1, хотя, может они клингонскую алгебру обсуждают? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, проще понять на примере.
Допустим, мы проверяем на простоту число 16 до квадратного корня этого числа — 4.

Получим:
2 * 8 = 16 и
4 * 4 = 16.

Мы можем начать проверять дальше по циклу и обнаружим, также что 8 * 2 = 16, но такой вариант мы уже учли ранее. Поскольку ОБА множителя не могут быть больше 4, то второй множитель дальше будет только уменьшаться.

Answer (score 0):

если число N равно произведению двух других, то одно из них не больше корня из N, а другое не меньше корня из N.

Из этого следует, что если число N не делится ни на одно из чисел 2,3,4,…,"корень из N", то оно не делится и ни на одно из чисел "корень из N"+1,…,N−2,N−1, так как если есть делитель больше корня (не равный N), то есть делитель и меньше корня (не равный 1). Поэтому в цикле for достаточно проверять числа не до N, а до корня.

Comment: Зачем повторять имеющийся ответ?